# Why is the "Posts created" column (or its tooltip) on the admin summary page so incorrect?

Tags: feature-request, moderators

On the admin summary page (/admin), with the history tab showing and the filter set to "all," I see the following when I sort on the "Posts created" column:

[image: Posts created for moderators is 740]

The tooltip for the column distinctly says "**questions and answers created.**"  But according to the "activity" tab of my profile, I've only created 271 answers and 120 questions:

[image]
[image]

As a moderator, these numbers include my deleted posts (of which there aren't that many anyway).

So what can be the explanation for a discrepancy of this magnitude?  I've only created 391 posts, and yet this table says I've created almost double that.  For other moderators, the number seems to be much more accurate, within a handful of the number shown on the activity tab of the profile.

If there are some other posts out there that I'm not considering, can the tooltip be updated to mention what the most significant other options might be?

Comment: Wiki posts are not answers or questions.

Comment: @Oded Including, I presume, tag wikis?  Because I haven't done many (if any) community wiki posts.

Comment: Yeah - tag wikis and tag wiki summaries are posts. I was about to look into the DB to see exact numbers.

Comment: @Oded Thanks.  Perhaps then it would make sense for this question to be converted into a feature-request for modifying the tooltip.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Tooltip is completely wrong :D

Answer (score 7):

I looked it up:

- 120 Questions
- 271 Answers
- 172 tag wiki excerpts
- 176 tag wikis
- 1 moderator nomination (!)

Comment: [Only 4 deleted answers then](http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/687364)

Comment: @rene Only one, actually; I've posted a few answers since that data was updated, apparently.